# Is there exist integers a, b, c ,d, such as?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is there exist integers a, b, c, d, such as $a^2+b^2+2d^2=c^2$?
How to solved this problem?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: (1,1, 2, 1) and the easier (0,0,0,0) work

Comment: Are there any restrictions or conditions on the 4 values? For example, could d=0 and this reduces to Pythagorean triplets.

Comment: I want to build a triangle in the coordinate system so as to build on the hypotenuse of a right-angled triangles whose hypotenuse is vertical and horizontal sides! I hope that clearly written (it is Google Translate). I know now that it is possible, for example 1,4,5,2. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need at least one solution, take $a=b=d$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this does have a non-trivial solution. Take $a=b=d=1$ and $c=2$.